# Search for multiple object on tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I put a **searchBar** inside a **tableView** and I parse JSON into tableView and the search works but I want to search for multiple objects. This code works for latest filtered that is RequestBody. I want to search for both `requestTitle and RequestBody`.

How can I solve this issue?  `

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil ||  searchBar.text == "" {

        inSearchMode = false
        tableView.reloadData()
        view.endEditing(true)
    } else {

        inSearchMode = true
        _ = searchBar.text!.lowercased()
        filteredRequest = pdvRequest.filter({ (pdv: PdvRequest) -> Bool in
            return pdv.pdvRequestTitle.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        filteredRequest = pdvRequest.filter({ (pdv: PdvRequest) -> Bool in
            return pdv.pdvRequestBody.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())

        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }//END
`
```

Comment: the solution depends on what your policy is: __both__ the _title AND body_ must contain the search string or the __either__ the _title OR body_ should contain the search string – so, what is it? do you know what you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try , Use `||` to search text inside any of them or `&&` for content inside both

```
filteredRequest = pdvRequest.filter({ (pdv: PdvRequest) -> Bool in
    return pdv.pdvRequestTitle.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) && pdv.pdvRequestBody.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your searching policy is not clear at all there are two options here.

If the search term must be **both** in the title *AND* in the body, it would look like this:

```
let lowercaseTerm = searchText.lowercased()
filteredRequest = pdvRequest.filter({ (pdv: PdvRequest) -> Bool in
        return pdv.pdvRequestTitle.lowercased().contains(lowercaseTerm) && pdv.pdvRequestBody.lowercased().contains(lowercaseTerm)
    })
```

If the search term should be **either** in the title *OR* in the body, that would be the solution:

```
let lowercaseTerm = searchText.lowercased()
filteredRequest = pdvRequest.filter({ (pdv: PdvRequest) -> Bool in
    return pdv.pdvRequestTitle.lowercased().contains(lowercaseTerm) || pdv.pdvRequestBody.lowercased().contains(lowercaseTerm)
})
```